# One command/script to find and flush all masters in Redis cluster

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, devops

Can we run one command/script to find and flush all masters in Redis cluster?
I am trying to run `FLUSHALL` on all masters in my cluster at once. Also whenever one of my master fails, slave of that failed master becomes Master. so when it changes to master, it should run `FLUSHALL` command.
Are their any built-in functions to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redis-cli can do something like this with the following syntax:

```
redis-cli --cluster call 1.2.3.4:9876 flushall
```

Where the ip:port is one of your cluster's nodes. This will run the command on all nodes.

Comment: Will it work on slaves as well? I just wanna run on masters.

Comment: This would be executed on the masters and will be propagated to the replicas via the replication stream.

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://redis.io/commands/cluster-nodes and the related commands.

The output of `CLUSTER NODES` command is a space-separated CSV string, where each line represents a node in the cluster. The following is an example of output:

```
07c3...b91 127...1:30004@31004 slave e7d1eecce10fd6bb5eb35b9f99a514335d9ba9ca 0 1426238317239 4 connected
67ed...fa1 127...1:30002@31002 master - 0 1426238316232 2 connected 5461-10922
292f...f4f 127...1:30003@31003 master - 0 1426238318243 3 connected 10923-16383
6ec2...e01 127...1:30005@31005 slave 67ed2db8d677e59ec4a4cefb06858cf2a1a89fa1 0 1426238316232 5 connected
824f...ac3 127...1:30006@31006 slave 292f8b365bb7edb5e285caf0b7e6ddc7265d2f4f 0 1426238317741 6 connected
e7d1...9ca 127...1:30001@31001 myself,master - 0 0 1 connected 0-5460
```

Each line is composed of the following fields:

- id
- ip:port@cport
- flags
- master/slave
- ping-sent
- pong-recv
- config-epoch
- link-state
- slot slot ... slot

So with this command, you find all masters (and slaves), by type on the fourth field.

You would need to implement a monitor service to detect when to trigger your FLUSHALL commands.